# How can we generate the "day of year" or "week of year" in ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud

To create an automated email program, I am performing some action based on the week of year. I am referencing the [datepart() function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DatePart.htm), and want to convert NOW() into the current week of year - ie: Jan 15, 2019 --> 3.

I do not see documentation for native support of that conversion; so then I though to convert NOW() into current day of year - ie: Jan 15 2019 --> 15; Feb 1 --> 32 from which I could / 7 to get close to the week-of-year. I also don't see native support for this in ampscript.

As a workaround, I am generating the week-of-year in a tsql query while selecting subscribers in SFMC: `DatePart(weekday, GETDATE())`. This feels inefficient since it will generate the exact same value for every subscriber.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? What did you do? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no premade function inside AMPscript to do this, but luckily with a bit of math you can get this yourself.

You would grab the current date and then do a datediff compared to Jan 1st, and that will give you the day of year (adding one to it to include Jan 1). From there you divide by 7 and format to have no decimal and you then have week of year (adding one to include week 1).

For example:

```
%%[

set @today = NOW()
set @year = DatePart(@today,'year')
set @startDate = FormatDate(Concat("01/01/",@year),"MM/DD/YYYY")

set @dayofYear = ADD(DateDiff(@startDate,@today,'D'),1)
set @weekofYear = ADD(FormatNumber(DIVIDE(@dayofYear,7),"N0"),1)
]%%

Today: %%=v(@today)=%%<br>
Year: %%=v(@year)=%%<br>
StartDate: %%=v(@startDate)=%%<br>
DayofYear: %%=v(@dayofYear)=%%<br>
WeekofYear: %%=v(@weekofYear)=%%
```

Outputs:

```
Today: 5/22/2019 1:24:46 PM
Year: 2019
StartDate: 01/01/2019
DayofYear: 142
WeekofYear: 21
```

Comment: Aha! Great thought - just perform the math to find difference between today and Jan 1. Thanks for that answer! That should definitely work.
Granted, dividing dayofyear/7 doesn't always give exactly the right answer (think if Jan 1 was on fri/sat/sun, that would be week 52/53 of previous year though I suppose could evaluate that too if we needed), but for this project, will absolutely cover the requirements.
Thanks again!

Comment: yeah its not perfect, but with the +1 and rounding down will give the right WOY 99 out of 100 times