# How to add get year in to EDM?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I'm adjusting my email and wondering is that possible to make copy write footer to add dynamic year?

For example when email send on 2024 then the footer will shows 2024.

Sounds shall be easy to complete. But I'm using content block and not able to add script in to div...

Is there anyone know other ideas?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263356/how-can-we-generate-the-day-of-year-or-week-of-year-in-ampscript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [xtyear](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings) system string, also the [now()](https://ampscript.guide/now) and [getSendTime()](https://ampscript.guide/getsendtime) AMPscript functions.

You can mask the results of now() and getSendTime() with the [format()](https://ampscript.guide/format) or [formatDate()](https://ampscript.guide/formatDate) functions.

Most folks just use `xtyear`, because it's the easiest.